# Make large bullets without using background images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get large bullet points made with pseudo-elements and the content property (rather than images) and so I messed with the pixels until I got it about right.

[Here is the JsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/90sg1p4h/)

```css
#the-list {
  padding-left: 0;
}
#the-list li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
  color: #4F4F4F;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Segoe, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#the-list li + li {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#the-list li:before {
  content: "\002022";
  color: #7F7F7F;
  font-size: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: -52px;
}
#the-list li:hover:before {
  color: #00ADEE;
}
```

```html
<ul id="the-list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

The only problem I'm having at the moment is that the large font size of the pseudo-element content is causing the hover effect to not be positioned correctly. **To see what I mean, hover over the first bullet point (grey circle) and you'll see that the second bullet point goes blue.** Any idea how I can implement a quick fix?

Comment: Seems to work ok in IE

Comment: you can use the Unicode Number for a bullet and then some css to change the size  -- http://www.alt-codes.net/bullet_alt_codes.php

Comment: @Tasos That's what I'm doing ...

Comment: like this -- https://jsfiddle.net/wfhoL6y5/

Comment: The problem isn't with the large font size, it's with the positioning you are using to try to get them to line up. The hover works as expected when hovering over the actual list items. And works when you remove the absolute positioning.

Comment: @Anthony -- yeah thats right -- its needs to be displayed in one block

Comment: if you inspect the page where the bullet is here -- http://www.alt-codes.net/bullet_alt_codes.php -- its actaully using a table rather than a list to achieve that -- so that's another way of doing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `border-radius` to make the pseudo elements look like circles, rather than use the unicode font.

```css
#the-list {
  padding-left: 0;
}
#the-list li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
  color: #4F4F4F;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Segoe, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#the-list li + li {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#the-list li:before {
  content: "";
  background: #7F7F7F;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#the-list li:hover:before {
  background: #00ADEE;
}
```

```html
<ul id="the-list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: In addition, the circles can render with slightly jagged edges. If this is annoying you can soften is slightly with `box-shadow`... something like:   `box-shadow: 0 0 1px #7F7F7F;` with the color matching the circle background color. The slightly blurred edge is sometimes a better compromise to a rough edge.

Comment: Good point @misterManSam That makes some notable improvements.